# MagicMock the response to get data in python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, mocking, python-unittest, magicmock

I have below two functions which I am trying to write unittest case using magicMock.

```
import json
from unittest import mock
from unittest.mock import MagicMock
def get_response(m, time):
    response = get_data(m, time)
    return response

def my_method():
    m = ''
    time = "2019-08-30"
    resp = get_response(m, time)
    if resp.status_code = 200:
        data = json.loads(resp.text)
```

I am trying to write unittest case to get the response code and text using MagicMock:

```
ok_response_mock = MagicMock()
type(ok_response_mock).status_code = mock.PropertyMock(return_value=200)
ok_response_mock.text.return_value = "{'blah':'blah'}"

get_response = MagicMock()
get_response.return_value = ok_response_mock
```

But I am not getting this worked. The above method is not able to mock the `resp.text`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can mock `get_response` with a `Mock` object that returns a `Mock` object that has a `status_code` attribute of `200` and a `text` attribute of your mock JSON content:

```
import json
from unittest.mock import Mock

def my_method():
    m = ''
    time = "2019-08-30"
    resp = get_response(m, time)
    if resp.status_code == 200:
        print(json.loads(resp.text))

get_response = Mock(return_value=Mock(status_code=200, text='{"blah": "blah"}'))

my_method()
```

This outputs:

```
{'blah': 'blah'}
```

Since the default return value of a `Mock` object is a `Mock` object, you can also configure the `return_value` attribute of the `Mock` object like this, and it will work just as well:

```
get_response = Mock()
get_response.return_value.status_code = 200
get_response.return_value.text = '{"blah": "blah"}'
```